# How to stop an event propagation to a parent control?

Tags: uwp

I have a usercontrol where the main control is a grid which has a click event, but inside this I have a textview that when clicking will have other functionality, however when you click on the textview it activates both your event and the grid , and I can not find how to get only the textview event to be activated.

Is there any way to only activate the TextView click event if I click on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is confusing since UWP Grid do not have click event and TextView. So I'm not so sure whether you are actually on a UWP platform and whether your code is in C#. Anyway, as the only tag is about UWP, I will post the workaround for UWP platform for your reference. Please see the code below:

```
 private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("grid tapped");
    }

    private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("textblock tapped");

    }
```

Actually as you can see, if you set e.Handled=true in your textblock, then the route event will only be handle by your textblock. Hope this is what you actually need.

Comment: I was actually wrong and it was the tapped event, but it served me the same way. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Aldo If it works please mark it as the answer so that it could also benefit for other communities who has the same problem.